# Difference: cin.getline() and getline(cin, st)

Tags: c++, stl

Which one is better and preferred? I am really finding the reading API confusing.

Answer (score 9):

The member version reads into a `char*`, the free version reads into a `std::string`. So prefer the free version! Use it like this:

```
std::istream & ins = /* ... */;
std::string line;
while (std::getline(ins, line))
{
  // process line
}
```