# What am I doing wrong with cin.getline()?

Tags: c++, getline

I am relatively new and inexperienced when it comes to programming, so I apologize if my code make anyone's eyes bleed.

Question #1:
My code wasn't working when I tried using cin.getline() and I keep getting the error "Could not find a match for  std::istream::getline(char[30], int, const char[2])", but when I tried using getline(cin, varName), it worked perfectly. I have used cin.getline() before using the same parameter but I never have that problem before.

Question #2:
Just curious. Which one is better? In my case, is it better to use cin.getline(...) or getline(cin, ___)? Or is there something even better than either one?
I tried reading [Difference: cin.getline() and getline(cin, st)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225035/difference-cin-getline-and-getlinecin-st) but I am not sure if thats a good answer.

I'll include both copies of the working and not working code. Please don't mind the names, these are just a section of a much larger assignment I was asked to complete.

Not working code:

```
#include<time.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class ElectricityBill
{
   private:
      char accountName[30];
      char address[50];
      tm dueDate;
      tm periodStartDate;
      tm periodEndDate;
   public:
      ElectricityBill();
      void print();
};

ElectricityBill::ElectricityBill()
{
   int dd, mm, yyyy;

   cout << "Input electricity bill data." << endl;

   cout << "Account name: ";
   cin.getline(accountName, 30, "\n");

   cout << "Address: ";
   cin.getline(address, 50, "\n");

   cout << "Start date: ";
   cin >> dd >> mm >> yyyy;
   periodStartDate.tm_mday = dd;
   periodStartDate.tm_mon  = mm;
   periodStartDate.tm_year = yyyy;

   cout << "End date: ";
   cin >> dd >> mm >> yyyy;
   periodEndDate.tm_mday = dd;
   periodEndDate.tm_mon  = mm;
   periodEndDate.tm_year = yyyy;

   cout << "Due date: ";
   cin >> dd >> mm >> yyyy;
   dueDate.tm_mday = dd;
   dueDate.tm_mon  = mm;
   dueDate.tm_year = yyyy;

   //next = NULL;
}
void ElectricityBill::print()
{
   cout << "Account Name: " << accountName << endl;
   cout << "Address     : " << address << endl;
   cout << "Start Date  : " << periodStartDate.tm_mday << "/" << periodStartDate.tm_mon << "/" << periodStartDate.tm_year << endl;
   cout << "End Date    : " << periodEndDate.tm_mday << "/" << periodEndDate.tm_mon << "/" << periodEndDate.tm_year << endl;
}

int main()
{
   ElectricityBill a;
   a.print();

   return 0;
}
```

Here's the copy of the working code when i use getline(cin, varName)..

```
#include<time.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class ElectricityBill
{
   private:
      string accountName;
      string address;
      tm dueDate;
      tm periodStartDate;
      tm periodEndDate;
   public:
      ElectricityBill();
      void print();
};

ElectricityBill::ElectricityBill()
{
   int dd, mm, yyyy;

   cout << "Input electricity bill data." << endl;

   cout << "Account name: ";
   getline(cin, accountName);

   cout << "Address: ";
   getline(cin, address);

   cout << "Start date: ";
   cin >> dd >> mm >> yyyy;
   periodStartDate.tm_mday = dd;
   periodStartDate.tm_mon  = mm;
   periodStartDate.tm_year = yyyy;

   cout << "End date: ";
   cin >> dd >> mm >> yyyy;
   periodEndDate.tm_mday = dd;
   periodEndDate.tm_mon  = mm;
   periodEndDate.tm_year = yyyy;

   cout << "Due date: ";
   cin >> dd >> mm >> yyyy;
   dueDate.tm_mday = dd;
   dueDate.tm_mon  = mm;
   dueDate.tm_year = yyyy;

   //next = NULL;
}
void ElectricityBill::print()
{
   cout << "Account Name: " << accountName << endl;
   cout << "Address     : " << address << endl;
   cout << "Start Date  : " << periodStartDate.tm_mday << "/" << periodStartDate.tm_mon << "/" << periodStartDate.tm_year << endl;
   cout << "End Date    : " << periodEndDate.tm_mday << "/" << periodEndDate.tm_mon << "/" << periodEndDate.tm_year << endl;
}

int main()
{
   ElectricityBill a;
   a.print();

   return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question #1

```
cin.getline(accountName, 30, '\n');
```

The third argument to getline is a char, not a string. Also the default value is '\n' for the above code is exactly the same as

```
cin.getline(accountName, 30);
```

Question #2

`std::string` is superior to a char array for most purposes. For instance with `std::string` you have no upper limit on how big the string can be.

Comment: Thanks! I should have known better. Now i feel like i want to stab myself for a mistake like this.

Comment: the char array version is actually the original version, then i came across getline when reading Stanley Lippman's C++ primer.

Comment: You don't need to do that, everybody makes mistakes and you may not be different. At time I would have put a simicolon more or less and despite staring at it cannot see it. :)

Comment: getline() is superior compared to cin.getline() ? I see...
I'll select this as the answer tomorrow unless someone came up with a better answer :) Gotta catch the bus.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try this

```
cin.getline(accountName, 30, '\n');
```

instead of this.

```
cin.getline(accountName, 30, "\n");
```

The '\n' is a character rather than a string.

Comment: Yep. Thats the mistake I made. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome Vince. Please mark as answer if you may. Thank you.